# Master theorem: what to do with constant in parenthesis?

Tags: master-theorem

In analysis of algorithms, we sometimes use the (unsimplified) Master Theorem for recurrence relations.

What should be done in the case that there is a constant factor in the numerator following T?

$$
T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{5n}{8}\right) + 1
$$

Does b simply equal $\frac{5}{8}$? This seems a contradiction to the Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the general form of the recurrences solved by the Master theorem is stated as:
$$
T(n) = aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + f(n).
$$

In your recurrence you have $a=2$, $b=\frac{8}{5}$, and $f(n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion stems from the fact that the MT is often stated in the form
$$T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n),$$
so $b$ is expected to be some constant larger than 1.
The recurrence relation you give is not in this form, so to rewrite it to fit the form you know, write $T(n) = 2T(n / (8 / 5)) + 1$ and take it from there.